# Function running in Simulator, not on device

Tags: iphone, simulator

I'm writting some code to handle SerwerChanges. I have a function in class ServerChangesArchive:

```
+(id) httpQueueWithLogin:(NSString*) _login password:(NSString*) _password lastSyncTime:(NSDate*) date;
```

When I run this function using Simulator everything works fine, but on device I'm getting

```
[ServerChangesArchive httpQueueWithLogin:self.login password:self.password lastSyncTime:self.date] 

Incident Identifier: F302A702-69BA-4388-AF9C-CE54426008D4
CrashReporter Key:   2aa75e68ee087cee2b81667dfaa1d8e3b0f5454b
Process:         APPName [420]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E4DAF458-9687-4BDC-A7BC-30357743A33E/Listonic.app/Listonic
Identifier:      APPNAme
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-11-08 10:56:54.439 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.2 (7D11)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x883841bd
Crashed Thread:  5

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3272e4b8 0x3272d000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x32731094 0x3272d000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                 0x32da4002 0x32d4d000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                 0x32da3c18 0x32d4d000 + 355352
4   GraphicsServices               0x31bb936c 0x31bb5000 + 17260
5   UIKit                          0x30bf3c28 0x30bf0000 + 15400
6   UIKit                          0x30bf2228 0x30bf0000 + 8744
7   APPName                       0x00002686 main (main.m:13)
8   APPName                       0x0000261c start + 44

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3272e4b8 0x3272d000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x32731094 0x3272d000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                 0x32da4002 0x32d4d000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                 0x32da3c18 0x32d4d000 + 355352
4   WebCore                        0x32f486f0 0x32ec4000 + 542448
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327be720 0x3272d000 + 595744
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x32730916 0x3272d000 + 14614
2   Foundation                     0x33f389c8 0x33f29000 + 63944
3   APPName                       0x00006fc8 -[Syncer requestPump] (Syncer.m:114)
4   Foundation                     0x33f7cac6 0x33f29000 + 342726
5   Foundation                     0x33f2ad0e 0x33f29000 + 7438
6   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3272e4b8 0x3272d000 + 5304
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x32731094 0x3272d000 + 16532
2   CoreFoundation                 0x32da4002 0x32d4d000 + 356354
3   CoreFoundation                 0x32da3c18 0x32d4d000 + 355352
4   Foundation                     0x33f83998 0x33f29000 + 371096
5   Foundation                     0x33f7cac6 0x33f29000 + 342726
6   Foundation                     0x33f2ad0e 0x33f29000 + 7438
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327532f0 0x3272d000 + 156400
1   CoreFoundation                 0x32d6d7e2 0x32d4d000 + 133090
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x326704dc 0x32665000 + 46300
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x32670550 0x32665000 + 46416
2   libobjc.A.dylib                0x32671314 0x32665000 + 49940
3   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3266cf54 0x32665000 + 32596
4   libobjc.A.dylib                0x32668f20 0x32665000 + 16160
5   APPName                       0x0004e9e2 -[ServerChanges requestDidFinishThread:] (ServerChanges.m:352)
6   Foundation                     0x33f7cac6 0x33f29000 + 342726
7   Foundation                     0x33f2ad0e 0x33f29000 + 7438
8   libSystem.B.dylib              0x327587b0 0x3272d000 + 178096

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x3841bd01    r1: 0xffffffff      r2: 0x00000005      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x883841bd    r5: 0x3841bd01      r6: 0x000c39d4      r7: 0x046779cc
    r8: 0x3841bd88    r9: 0x002fc098     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x38332118    sp: 0x046779b4      lr: 0x32670558      pc: 0x326704dc
  cpsr: 0x20000010
```

Device even don't get into this function body. Starting is causing the problem.

Could anyone tell me how to fix it or where to search for explenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was .xcodeproj problem. After removing *.perspectivev3 and *.pbxuser files is everything good :)

Answer (score 2):

The crashlog shows that the crash is caused by some of your code in:

```
-[ServerChanges requestDidFinishThread:]
```

Or more specifically in the file ServerChanges.m at line 352.

I'll suggest starting your search for the bug here.